# Using service classes and repository classes in projects?

Tags: c#, .net

I've been entering the advanced stage of C# recently and I've seen a lot of applications that implement losely coupling and dependency injection. I've seen the word "Service" a lot associated with classes, I suppose you would call them Service classes? I've also seen classes in this project which include the word Repository, say you has a called 'Player', there would be 2 more classes 'PlayerService' and 'PlayerRepository' classes.

I've checked Linda, TreeHouse, Udemy and many other sites. I've even google the subject but it seems to bring up hundreds of results all leading to different things. None of these links really answer my question in simple plain detail, atleast none that I can understand.

Can anyone help explain this? Why do I need them, when should I use them, what are they?

Comment: It's meant for separation of concern. You can try to learn SOLID principles in order to understand why.

Comment: The information is out there, you just need to find it. Voting to close as too broad for the Q&A format of SO.

Answer (score 0):

Well, hard to make a specific explanation without seeing the code but in general terms the concept of a Repository refers to data layer components and the term service - mostly in ASP.NET world refers to business layer components.

You separate these layers from each other so they can be maintained, tested, expanded in isolation. Ideal architectures expose the functionality of these layers via Interfaces - especially the Repository layer. On the Service layer you can take these dependencies through constructor as Interfaces. Using an IoC container and Dependency Injection patterns, you can then register concrete classes to these interfaces and build your objects in a central location aka. Object Composition Root. that allows you easily manage your dependencies in a central location, rather then each dependency instantiated, passed around in scattered places within your code.

This answer is just a pointer to give you an overview. These are topics you should delve deeper by self research and digest.

Answer (score 0):

The Repository pattern is used to abstract away how a class is persisted. This allows you to change the underlying Database or ORM mapper without influencing the persisted classes. See [Using Repository Pattern for Abstracting Data Access from a Cache and Data Store](http://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/using-repository-pattern-for-abstracting-data-access-from-a-cache-and-data-store/).

A service is used if multiple classes are taking part in a certain usecase and none of these classes should have the responsibility to coordinate the other classes. (Maybe these classes do not even hold direct references to each other.) In this case, put the code that handles the interplay between the classes into a service method and pass the affected objects to it.

Note that if the affected classes are in a direct parent-child relationship, you could let the parent coordinate its children directly, without introducing a service. But this might lead to code that is hard to understand.

Let me give an example: assume we want to commit Transactions. After a Transaction was commited, we want to update the Person who has the transaction with the (denormalized) timestamp of the most recent transaction. As you can see, `Person` does not hold a direct reference to the transaction.

```
public class Person {

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime? LastTransactionTimestamp { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction {

     public long Id { get; set; }

     public long PersonId { get; set; }

     public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

     public void Commit() {
         Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
     }
}
```

Now we have the problem where we should put the logic. If we put it into the `Person` class, it would need Repository access to load the Transaction (because it holds no direct reference). But it should only be concerned with storing its own data, not loading unrelated data from the DB. If we put it into the `Transaction` class, it does not know if it was the latest Transaction for this Person (because it does not see the other transactions).

So the solution is to put the logic into a service. If the service needs DB access, we inject a repository into it.

```
public class PersonTransactionService {

    private readonly IDbSet<Transaction> _allTransactions;

    public PersonTransactionService(IDbSet<Transaction> allTransactions) {
        _allTransactions = allTransactions;
    }

    public void Commit(Person person, Transaction transaction) {
        transaction.Commit();

        var mostRecent = _allTransactions
            .Where(t => t.PersonId == person.Id)
            .OrderBy(t => t.Timestamp)
            .LastOrDefault();

        if (mostRecent != null) {
            person.LastTransactionTimestamp = mostRecent.Timestamp;
        }
    }
}
```